# Use coffeescript in jade templates

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, pug

I like coffeescript and I like haml-based template engines. Im trying to figure out how do I use Jade with CoffeeScript? And I dont mean client scripts embedded in html, I mean server side logic.

Actually I found package exactly I want, but its very outdated: [jade-coffee](https://github.com/ddopson/jade-coffeescript)

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Just use express to render jade, and jade will render coffee via `:coffee`

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if I'm understanding the question right or not but if you are trying to write coffeescript in jade you can make use of the Jade language filters.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/

Hope this helps!